# requirejs / backbone : declare a global function / variable

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette, require

Is it possible to declare a **global function** in a backbone / marionnette app, that calls a precise module's function?

This question may sound weird since I personally would suggest not to do this at all, because using modules is awesome and keep app structure clean. I need a global function because there is a module / function that I use everywhere, in all single view / template of my app. The function is **lang.item()**. For example:

```
lang.item(ID, p1, p2, p3, ... )
```

I use this everywhere, with a module I called "lang". Example :

```
define([ 'backbone', 'lang'], function(Backbone, lang){
   return Backbone.View.extend({
       ...
       template: _.template('<%= lang.item("welcome") %> <%=username%>'),
       onError: function(){
            this.ui.error.html(lang.item('wrong_login'));
       }
       ...
   });
});
```

I always have to include the "lang" module so I can use it. Since I call it and use it everywhere, I would love to use a simple global function like **lang(ITEM_ID)**, anywhere, when I need it, without having to include the "lang" module everytime.

```
define(['Backbone'], function(Backbone){
   return Backbone.View.extend({
       ...
       template: _.template('<%= lang("welcome") %> <%=username%>'),
       onError: function(){
            this.ui.error.html(lang('wrong_login'));
       }
       ...
   });
});
```

Someone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using this in your `main` javascript file, used by `requireJS`:

```
define('init', function (require) {
    ...
    window.lang = require('lang');
    ...
});

// Initialize the application.
require(['init']);
```

Personally, I do not find this offensive to any coding standards. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Then I would need to call lang.item(ITEM_ID) or window.lang.item(ITEM_ID)?